# Why my tables' names are converted into lowercase in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I am using wamp server 2.0 on Windows XP. Whenever I create a table with some uppercases in name, it is converted to lowercase.

For example:

```
I create: UserInfo
phpmyadmin convert it to: userinfo
```

I am using ubuntu/phpmyadmin in office but this problem does exists there.

from where can I fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a directive for forcing table names to lower case.

You want to set the lower_case_table_names value to 0.

You can read more about it from MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: in which file I will set lower_case_table_names to 0.

Comment: I updated my answer to give a better link. It's a system variable that you set. The MySQL documentation can tell you how.

Comment: c:/mysql/my.ini for example. but I'd go with lower_case_table_names = 2, not 0, because with 2 "table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase".

Comment: In Wamp go to C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\my.ini  find [mysqld] and add the line: lower_case_table_names = 2

Comment: Need to restart MySql service to apply  the changes in my.ini file

Comment: did as directed, after adding that line, the services will not restart.

Answer (score 23):

I've tried what's been suggested here, i must inform that

```
lower_case_table_names = 0
```

doesn't work in xampp, it crashes MySQL service at the moment you restart it. Yet

```
lower_case_table_names = 2
```

didn't crash, and apparently worked... at least it allowed me to insert a db with camel case.

Comment: Using `lower_case_table_names = 0` crashed it for me too (MySQL 5.7, Windows 10). I was unable to start the service again after changing it. Using `lower_case_table_names = 2` worked

Comment: The case was the same for me WAMP64, Windows 10, `lower_case_table_names = 0` crashed MySQL 5.7.19 `lower_case_table_names = 2` worked.

Comment: In MySql 8.0. only 1 value works. Service crashes immediately if I use 0 or 2. I'm used standard installer for mysql

Answer (score 7):

In windows the default value for `lower_case_table_names = 1`.

You need to change or add this value to my.ini file in your mysql folder..

If this line is not found, then add it under `[mysqld]`

```
lower_case_table_names = 0
```

And then restart the wamp services, it will work :D

Comment: You should use lower_case_table_names = 2 when using Windows.

Answer (score 4):

You must find file **my.ini** in your mysql folder and change, or add this line:

```
lower_case_table_names value = 0
```

Comment: Add it underneath [mysqld] on a new line.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find file my.ini in your mysql folder and change, or add this line at bottom:

lower_case_table_names = 2

Answer (score 3):

- Step 1: open your MySQL configuration file: [drive]\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
  or open xampp click on mysql -> config then open my.ini file
- Step 2: Search [mysqld] for: # The MySQL server [mysqld] in my.ini file
- Step 3: Add this :lower_case_table_names=2
- Step 4: save the file and restart MySQL service or (Xampp)

Answer (score 2):

It was not phpMyAdmin. MySQL did this.

p.s. It is a bad practice to use camelCase in databases.  Use _underlines instead. :)

Comment: because almost all databases does not make difference between lower and upper cases.

Comment: I had a WordPress plugin developer who used camelCasing in their plugin tables. Are you saying that it should not be a regular practice?