# Migrating SQL Database, Capatilized fields

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-migration

So I have a point of sale software that is using WAMP Server locally. Ive set up a Ubuntu server with MySQL.  I'm trying to move the sql server on wamp from the windows machine to the ubuntu machine. Everything imports fine. But the original database fields are all lower case and for some unknown reason it seems my point of sales is looking for uppercase fields. I dont really understand whats happening.

All I know is that if i import the sql file into the unix system, and point the pos software at the sql db it says that it doesn't detect the database and then trys to recreate the fields with capital titles.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: [Why my tables' names are converted into lowercase in phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659684/why-my-tables-names-are-converted-into-lowercase-in-phpmyadmin)

You need to change your configuration so `lower_case_table_names` is `0`.

Comment: the software is looking for uppercase tables. Is there anyway I can convert my lowercase table to uppercase?

Comment: Check the configuration option I mentioned above.  If that doesn't work, you may have to rename your tables.