# Doctrine Schema Object creation and Casing

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm investigating an issue related to :

- Doctrine 2.* on Symfony2 2.3 LTS with a MySQL server (5.1.73 and 5.7.9)

Objects created in the database (Schema and entities) don't reflect the same casing as define in the Entities and parameters file.
    i.e: `database_name: TestDB` will create 'testdb' instead of 'TestDB'     i.e:`\....Bundle\Entity\Test:
    type: entity
    table: Test` will create an entity (table) 'test' instead of 'Test', this both while using YML or Annotations. Thereby , causing ***PDO Exception*** of table not found. 
  Is there a way to making sure that database object naming respect the ones defined into the project?

Comment: Try reformat everything (database name, table name, columns, indexes, etc) to underscore (lowercase with underscores). It might not allow you to name things that way you want but it stops most naming issues... apart from reserved words.

Comment: Maybe the issue is MySQL not Doctrine? See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) provided by [craigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2600812/craigh), i changed the setting of the `lower_case_table_names = 2`. This will allow the lookup to transform the lookup to lowercase while respecting the Create Statement Casing.

Below are supporting questions related to the same issue:

- [Where to change the value of lower_case_table_names=2 on windows xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550789/where-to-change-the-value-of-lower-case-table-names-2-on-windows-xampp)
- [Why my tables' names are converted into lowercase in phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659684/why-my-tables-names-are-converted-into-lowercase-in-phpmyadmin)